# Как создать библиотеку иконок?

Tags: delphi-xe2, delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-7, delphi-xe

Всем привет! Не нашел подробного описания в интернете по созданию библиотеки иконок.  Прошу помогите ссылкой или инструкцией.

Comment: Можно сделать просто DLL-ку без полезного кода, но в которую в качестве ресурсов положить иконки. Только смысл затеи?

Comment: @Nofate ♦ спортивный интерес: хочу создавать свои наборы иконок именно в виде библиотек.

Comment: @АлександрЪ единственный способ описал **Nofate**. Других способов нет.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего в ресурсах. Можно и в ImageList, только придётся дополнительный код писать. Мы у себя в ресурах храним.